# How can you make \b accept words that start with '+' using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

```
re.search(r"\b\+359\b","Is your phone number +359 887438?")
```

Why is this regex not finding `+359`  and how can i make `\b` consider words starting with `+`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't alter `\b`'s behaviour. You'd have to use a different anchor; like `\B`, which matches anywhere *not* at the start or end of a word; it is the inverse of `\b`:

```
\B\+359\b
```

This again matches if there is no word character preceding `+`, which itself is a non-word character. Where `\b` can only match between a word and nonword character (so `WORD\bNONWORD` or `NONWORD\bWORD`), `\B` needs two nonword or two word characters to match (so `WORD\BWORD` or `NONWORD\BNONWORD`). As `+` is a nonword character, whatever comes before `+` must *also* be a non-word character.

Alternatively, you can use a negative look-behind:

```
(?<!\w)\+359\b
```

The `(?<!\w)` negative look-behind assertion only matches a position where there is no word character preceding the position.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"\b\+359\b","Is your phone number +359 887438?")
>>> re.search(r"\B\+359\b","Is your phone number +359 887438?")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10cf03850>
>>> re.search(r"(?<!\w)\+359\b","Is your phone number +359 887438?")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10cf03d30>
```

Comment: Is "\B" supported in Python's regex?

Comment: What does the first part do ?

Comment: Hah -- negating the negations is hurting my head. The OP suggested `\b\+x` in accordance to `NOTWORD\bWORD`, but  then with a `+` in between. It does not work because `\b` needs a word boundary. So can you use `\B` then? (Ed.) Okay, that's a Yes :-)

Comment: @Jongware: You can, since `\B` can only match `NONWORD\BNONWORD` or `WORD\BWORD`. And `+` makes one side `NONWORD` so the other side has to be `NONWORD` too.